# Git, how to I update the remote origin to my local master

Tags: git

I have two remote repositories origin and origin2 and one local master branch.

Origin tracks master. master, origin/master and origin/HEAD are the same.

I want the remote `origin2/master` to match `origin/master` but I don t know how to do that.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Did you try to `git push origin2 master?`

Answer (score 1):

> > origin2/master to match origin/master but I don t know how to do that.

You simply need to merge the 2 branches if you want them to include the same code.
If you simply want to place the second branch on the other repo so simply push it to the other remote.

Git can have multiple remotes and it doesnt care where the code came from.
You can push/pull branches to as may repo as you can (as long as they share some kind of history or the merge will fail)

[image]